# Multiple threads in PHP sharing same singletons

Tags: php, multithreading

I know multiple ways of threading in PHP

One of them is `$thread->run();`, second one is opening http request to separate script;

I would like to stick to first one...

Is singleton pattern of something i.e. database, shared between the threads, or each get separate one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each get separate memory.

That means PHP will do a copy of memory for each thread. However if content of memory is not data but handles (or pointers) to external resources, there is no particular difference.

Singletons only guarantee their invariants in single thread.

You want to share some data use `shm_*` functions for shared memory.